# Performing good forecasts for the GDP

Tags: gdp, applied-econometrics

What forecasting models would you recommend to forecast the GDP?

Through a quick research I have found that VEC, VAR, SVAR models are the most common. Are they though good forecasters? Or are they just good at "analyzing" the sample(through Granger tests, IRF's etc) and bad out-of-sample forecasters?

What about the unvariate autoregresive family, Or other types of models? Which would be better in your experience for forecasting this variable?

Thanks in advance